# Fitting long Table using \documentclass{elsarticle}

Tags: tables, longtable

Hi i have a problem with fitting the table using the Elsevier elsarticle documentclass, here my code and my output

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
  \usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
  \usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
 \usepackage{xparse}  
 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \usepackage{natbib}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsthm} 
 \usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} 
  \usepackage{placeins}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{cuted}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}       
  \usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, threeparttable}
   \usepackage{xparse}    
   \usepackage{xstring}
   \usepackage{dcolumn}
   \usepackage{relsize}
   \usepackage{varioref}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \hypersetup{colorlinks = true, allcolors = blue}
    \usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} 
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                                 %%%%asterisk in Table%%%%
    \usepackage{xcolor}
   \newcommand\tc[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \newcommand{\Risk}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Risk}}\nolimits}
   \newcommand{\CEOPC}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape CEO\_PC}}\nolimits}
   \newcommand{\Boardind}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Board\_ind}}\nolimits}
   \newcommand{\OwnP}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape OwnP}}\nolimits}
   \newcommand{\OwnF}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape OwnF}}\nolimits}
   \newcommand{\ZScore}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Z\_Score}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\NPLs}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape NPLs}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\NPL}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape NPL}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\LnZ}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Ln\_Z}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\LnZscore}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Ln\_ZScore}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\CCB}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape CCB}}\nolimits}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 \newcommand{\LnTA}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LnTA}}\nolimits}
 \newcommand{\ECTA}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape ECTA}}\nolimits}
 \newcommand{\LTQ}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LTQ}}\nolimits}
 \newcommand{\PRF}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape PRF}}\nolimits}
 \newcommand{\EFF}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape EFF}}\nolimits}
 \newcommand{\LEV}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LEV}}\nolimits}
  \newcommand{\LG}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LG}}\nolimits}
  \newcommand{\AG}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape AG}}\nolimits}
  \newcommand{\DIV}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape DIV}}\nolimits}
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
     \NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
       {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
       \NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcl{O{9}m}
         {\multicolumn{#1}{@{}l}{#2}}
          \crefname{equation}{eq.}{eq.} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

   \begin{document}

  \begin{table}[ht]  
   \sisetup{table-format=-2.5,  
     table-number-alignment=center, 
     table-space-text-pre =(, 
     table-space-text-post=$^{***}$, 
     table-align-text-pre=false, 
     table-align-text-post=false}
    \centering          
     \caption{Effect of Politically connected CEO's on banks' risk-taking Behavior}
    \label{tab2}
     \begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S}}
     \toprule
      \thead{Variable} & {\thead{$\NPLs$}} & {\thead{$\ZScore$}} \\
      \midrule
      \multirow{2}[1]{*}{Constant}     & -0.1064\tc{***} & 5.0727\tc{***} \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{}             & {(}-3.420{)}     & {(}15.355{)} \\    
       \addlinespace
      \multirow{2}[0]{*}{$\NPL_{it-1}$} & 0.6014\tc{***}   & \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{}              & {(}5.730{)}  & \\
      \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LnZ_{it-1}$} &     &  0.5110\tc{***} \\
     \multicolumn{1}{c}{}               &     & {(}5.830{)} \\
     \addlinespace
   \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\CEOPC_{it}$} & 6.2810\tc{***}   & 0.1151 \\
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                 & {(}12.450{)} & {(}1.478{)} \\ 
    \addlinespace
    \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\Boardind$} & -0.2450\tc{**}    & -0.2401\tc{***}  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}             & {(}-2.260{)} & {(}-9.414{)} \\               
    \addlinespace
   \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\OwnF$} & -0.0103\tc{***}  & 0.0345\tc{**} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}         & {(}-2.605{)} & {(}2.520{)} \\                
    \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\OwnP$} & -0.0101\tc{*}    & 0.0301\tc{*} \\
     \multicolumn{1}{c}{}         & {(}-1.910{)} & {(}1.902{)} \\           
     \addlinespace
    \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LnTA$} & 0.0171\tc{**}    &-0.2791\tc{***} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}     & {(}2.120{)} & {(}-3.830{)} \\                    
      \addlinespace
       \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LTQ$} & -0.1854\tc{*} & -0.4525\\
       \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & {(}-0.450{)} & {(}-0.390{)} \\
      \addlinespace
      \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\PRF$} & -0.5240\tc{*} & -0.0520 \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & {(}-3.065{)} & {(}-1.243{)} \\                 
       \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\EFF$} & 0.0262\tc{**} & -0.0861\tc{***} \\
     \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & {(}1.733{)} & {(}-3.350{)} \\
   \addlinespace
    \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LEV$} & -0.5640\tc{***} & \\
     \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & {(}-1.430{)} &  \\  
    \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LG$} & -0.0270 &  \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & {(}-4.930{)} &  \\ 
   \addlinespace
   \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\AG$} &  & 0.0612\tc{***} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & {(}0.905{)} \\ 
   \addlinespace
   \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\DIV$} &  & 0.3120\tc{**} \\
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & {(}2.120{)} \\ 
     \midrule 
     Year dummy                         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Yes} \\
      Arellano-Bond test for AR(1)       &   1.156        &  2.452 \\
      Arellano-Bond test for AR(2)       &   0.652         & 1.562 \\
      P-value                            &   00.00          & 00.00 \\
      Sargan test                        & 12.02\tc{***}   & 41.02\tc{***} \\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
      \smallskip

     \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
     \small
    \textit{Note:} This table reports SGMM estimation results of \Cref{eq:1} where non-performing 
     loans to total loans ($\NPL$), and Z-score ($\LnZ$) are the dependent variables for bank $i$ and 
      year $t$. The $\NPL_{i,t-1}$ and $\LnZ_{it-1}$ are lagged dependent variables. $\CEOPC_{it}$ 
   takes a value of one if the bank has explicit political connection,and zero otherwise. $\OwnP$ and $\OwnF$ denotes the Private and Foreign Ownership type . For bank level control variables, The main explanatory variables are defined as follows : Bank size ($\LnTA$), Liquidity ($\LTQ$), Profitability ($\PRF$), Efficiency($\EFF$),  Leverage ($\LEV$), Loan growth ($\LG$), Asset growth ($\AG$) and Diversification ($\DIV$). Detailed definitions for each variable can be found in Section~\ref{sec:Data_variables}. T-statistics are between parentheses.The Sargan test justifies the validity of the over identifying restrictions. Statistical significance indicates \enspace *** $p < 0.01$; \enspace ** $p < 0.05$;\enspace * $p < 0.10$. 
      \end{minipage}
      \end{table}
      \end{document}
```

Output Table 1:

[image]

Code For Table with multiple columns

```
       \documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
       \usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
        \usepackage{xparse}  
        \usepackage{siunitx}
        \usepackage{natbib}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \usepackage{amsthm} 
        \usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} 
        \usepackage{placeins}
        \usepackage{float}
        \usepackage{cuted}
        \usepackage[english]{babel}
        \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}       
        \usepackage{makecell, multirow, threeparttable}

         \usepackage{longtable} %<--- added

          \usepackage{xparse}    
          \usepackage{xstring}
           \usepackage{dcolumn}
           \usepackage{relsize}
          \usepackage{varioref}
          \usepackage{hyperref}
          \hypersetup{colorlinks = true, allcolors = blue}
          \usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
           %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
           \usepackage{xcolor}
          \newcommand\tc[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
          %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
       \newcommand{\LnTA}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LnTA}}\nolimits}
       \newcommand{\ECTA}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape ECTA}}\nolimits}
       \newcommand{\LTQ}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LTQ}}\nolimits}
       \newcommand{\PRF}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape PRF}}\nolimits}
       \newcommand{\EFF}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape EFF}}\nolimits}
       \newcommand{\LEV}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LEV}}\nolimits}
        \newcommand{\LG}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LG}}\nolimits}
         \newcommand{\AG}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape AG}}\nolimits}
         \newcommand{\DIV}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape DIV}}\nolimits}

     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

       \DeclareRobustCommand{\variablename}[1]{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape #1}}\nolimits}
        \newcommand{\CEOPCGOVOFF}{\variablename{CEO}_{\variablename{PC}_{\variablename{GOVOFF}}}}
         \newcommand{\CEOPCPPM}{\variablename{CEO}_{\variablename{PC}_{\variablename{PPM}}}}
         \newcommand{\CEOPCPPM}{\variablename{CEO}_{\variablename{PC}_{\variablename{PPM}}}}
           \newcommand{\Controls}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Controls}}\nolimits}

                      \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
                      \NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
                      {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
                   \NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcl{O{9}m}
                    {\multicolumn{#1}{@{}l}{#2}}
                   \crefname{equation}{eq.}{eq.} 

    %\usepackage{lipsum}

     \begin{document}
     \begin{table}[h]
         \sisetup{input-open-uncertainty  = ,
      input-close-uncertainty = ,
      table-space-text-pre    = (,
      table-space-text-post   = ***,
      table-format            = 3.3,
     table-align-text-pre    = false,
     table-align-text-post   = false}

   \centering
   \caption{Effect of CEO's political identity on banks' risk-taking 
  Behavior including interactions with Ownership concentration } 
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{S} @{}}
    \toprule
   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Credit risk}}
   & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textit{Insolvency risk}}  \\
   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{\NPLs}}
   & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textit{\ZScore}} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
     & {Model} & {Model} & {Model} & {Model} \\
     & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(1)} & {(2)} \\
     \midrule
     Constant
     & -0.1183\tc{***} & -0.1369\tc{***} & 0.1087\tc{***} &  0.1011\tc{***} \\
            & (-3.180) & (-3.040) & (10.350) & (9.420) \\
            \addlinespace
     $\NPL$_{it-1}$$
            & 0.2335\tc{***}   &  0.3625\tc{***} & &   \\
            & (2.390) & (2.422)  & &   \\
            \addlinespace
            $\LnZ$_{it-1}$$
            & & & 0.5635\tc{***}  & 0.5725\tc{***} \\
            & &  & (6.020) & (5.245) \\
        \addlinespace
           \MAS
            & -0.0462\tc{***}& & -0.0852\tc{***} & \\
            & (-0.328) & & (-0.545) &  \\
         \addlinespace
            \ACS
           & & 0.0649 & &  0.0532   \\
           & & (0.890) & & (0.802) \\
           \addlinespace
             \CEOPCGOVOFF$_{it}$
           & 0.2856\tc{*}  & 0.2630 & 0.2846\tc{*} & 0.4125\tc{**} \\
             & (1.702) & (1.546) & (1.680) & (2.120) \\
             \addlinespace
              \CEOPCGOVOFF$_{it}$${}\times{}$\MAS$_{i,t}$
                     & 0.0630\tc{***} & & 0.0746\tc{***} & \\
                   & (0.010) & & (0.020) & \\
                   \addlinespace
                 \CEOPCGOVOFF$_{it}$${}\times{}$\ACS$_{i,t}$
                 & & 0.0726\tc{***} & & 0.0834\tc{***} \\
                & & (0.010) & & (0.022) \\
                 \addlinespace
                    \CEOPCPPM
             & 0.3288\tc{***}  & 0.3241\tc{***} & 0.0692\tc{***}  & 
                     0.0691\tc{**} \\
               & (0.042) & (0.040) & (0.011) & (0.010) \\
                    \addlinespace
                 \CEOPCPPM$_{it}$${}\times{}$\MAS$_{i,t}$
                    & 0.1576\tc{***}     & & 0.1640\tc{***}  & \\
                        & (0.020) & & (0.032) & \\
                    \addlinespace
                 \CEOPCPPM$_{it}$${}\times{}$\ACS$_{i,t}$
                  & & 0.3116\tc{***} & & 0.1728\tc{***} \\
                 & & (0.044)& & (0.039) \\
                            \addlinespace
                            \LnTA 
           & -0.0370\tc{**} & -0.0346\tc{***} & 0.0668\tc{***}  & 
   0.0716tc{***}  \\
       & (0.016) & (0.014) & (0.020) & (0.022) \\
        \addlinespace
        \LTQ 
  & -0.2904\tc{***} & -0.2840\tc{***} & 1.5091\tc{***} & 1.4960\tc{***} 
  \\
  & (0.076) & (0.056) & (0.354) & (0.338) \\
    \addlinespace
      \PRF 
         & -0.1825\tc{***} & -0.1827\tc{***} & -0.1802\tc{***} & 
   -0.1804\tc{***} \\
    & (0.021) & (0.020) & (0.020) & (0.20) \\
      \addlinespace
      \EFF
       & 1.0853\tc{***} & 1.0954\tc{***} & -0.1339 & -0.1362 \\
       & (0.256) & (0.258)  & (0.104) & (0.106) \\
     \addlinespace
      \LEV
      & -0.0810\tc{**} & -0.0430 &  & \\
      & (0.037) & (0.027) &  &  \\
      \addlinespace
      \LG 
      & 0.1141\tc{***} & 0.1128\tc{***} &  &  \\
      & (0.026) & (0.024) &  &  \\
      \addlinespace
       \AG
      &  &   & 0.0289\tc{*}  & 0.0290\tc{*} \\
      &  &  & (0.014) & (0.014) \\
      \addlinespace
       \DIV
       &  &   & 0.0598\tc{*}   & 0.0621\tc{*}\\
       &  &   & (0.028) & (0.032) \\
       \midrule
       Year dummy     & {Yes} & {Yes} & {Yes} & {Yes} \\
       Arellano-Bond test for AR(1)   & 0.546 & 0.314 & 0.178 & 0.112 \\
       Arellano-Bond test for AR(2)   & 0.143 & 0.139 & 0.143 & 0.140 \\
       Sargan test                    & 146.365 & 101.519 & 65.110 & 43.686 
             \\
         \bottomrule
          \addlinespace
          \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{This table reports SGMM estimation results of 
           $\Cref{eq:5}$.}\\
           \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{* $p<0.1$; ** $p<0.05$; *** $p<0.01$}\\
           \end{tabular}
           \label{tab5}
           \end{table}
           \end{document}
```

Output Table multiple columns :
[image]

Comment: You mention `longtable` but your code does not use this package. Did you already try to use `longtable` for your table? If so, what did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Apart from that, your MWE is not compilable since `\Cref` is not defined.

Comment: @leandriis Sorry i used the " \crefname{equation}{eq.}{eq.} " .

Comment: `\crefname` as well as `\Cref` require the `cleveref` package which is currently not included in your example code.

Comment: @leandriis i used \usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

Comment: What kind of output would you like to achive? Would you like to know how you can use the `longtable` package in order to split the table across multiplw pages or would you like to know how you can make sure the whole table fits onto a single page? Please clarify.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you so much for all the time and effort you put to help me. I was looking for a way to fits the whole table onto a single page using the Elsevier document class with 12pts, if it was not possible your answer is also very helpful.

Comment: Your table and its notes take up about 1.75 pages as you can see from my answer. How exactly would you like to squeeze that into a single page? The only chance, I currently see to fit all that information into a single page is drastically changing the table layout by using a total of 5 columns insead of 3 and showing the numbers in () right next to their corresponding value instead of below them. Apart from that, I am quite sure you won't be able to fit that many lines onto a single page, provided you want to keep your contents at a readable font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can use the `longtable` package in order to split your table across two consecutive pages:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
%  \usepackage{booktabs, tabularx} % Do not load packages more than once.
\usepackage{xparse}  
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} 
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}       
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, threeparttable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
  
\usepackage{longtable} %<--- added
  
\usepackage{xparse}    
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true, allcolors = blue}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                                 %%%%asterisk in Table%%%%
    
\newcommand\tc[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\Risk}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Risk}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\CEOPC}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape CEO\_PC}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\Boardind}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Board\_ind}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\OwnP}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape OwnP}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\OwnF}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape OwnF}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\ZScore}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Z\_Score}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\NPLs}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape NPLs}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\NPL}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape NPL}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\LnZ}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Ln\_Z}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\LnZscore}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Ln\_ZScore}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\CCB}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape CCB}}\nolimits}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\LnTA}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LnTA}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\ECTA}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape ECTA}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\LTQ}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LTQ}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\PRF}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape PRF}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\EFF}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape EFF}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\LEV}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LEV}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\LG}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape LG}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\AG}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape AG}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\DIV}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape DIV}}\nolimits}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
  {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcl{O{9}m}
  {\multicolumn{#1}{@{}l}{#2}}
\crefname{equation}{eq.}{eq.} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

{ 
   \sisetup{table-format=-2.5,  
     table-number-alignment=center, 
     table-space-text-pre =(, 
     table-space-text-post=\tc{***}, 
     table-align-text-pre=false, 
     table-align-text-post=false}      
 
   \begin{longtable}{l*{2}{S}}
     \caption{Effect of Politically connected CEO's on banks' risk-taking Behavior}
     \label{tab2}\\
     \toprule
     \thead{Variable} & {\thead{$\NPLs$}} & {\thead{$\ZScore$}} \\
     \midrule
     \endfirsthead
     \caption{Effect of Politically connected CEO's on banks' risk-taking Behavior - continued from previous page} \\
     \toprule
     \thead{Variable} & {\thead{$\NPLs$}} & {\thead{$\ZScore$}} \\
     \midrule
     \endhead
     \bottomrule
     \endfoot
     \multirow{2}[1]{*}{Constant}      & -0.1064\tc{***} & 5.0727\tc{***}  \\*
                                       & {(}-3.420{)}    & {(}15.355{)}    \\ \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}[0]{*}{$\NPL_{it-1}$} & 0.6014\tc{***}  &                 \\*
                                       & {(}5.730{)}     &                 \\ \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LnZ_{it-1}$} &                 &  0.5110\tc{***} \\*
                                       &                 & {(}5.830{)}     \\ \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\CEOPC_{it}$} & 6.2810\tc{***}  & 0.1151          \\*
                                       & {(}12.450{)}    & {(}1.478{)}     \\  \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\Boardind$}   & -0.2450\tc{**}  & -0.2401\tc{***} \\*
                                       & {(}-2.260{)}    & {(}-9.414{)}    \\ \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\OwnF$}       & -0.0103\tc{***} & 0.0345\tc{**}   \\*
                                       & {(}-2.605{)}    & {(}2.520{)}     \\ \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\OwnP$}       & -0.0101\tc{*}   & 0.0301\tc{*}    \\*
                                       & {(}-1.910{)}    & {(}1.902{)}     \\ \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LnTA$}       & 0.0171\tc{**}   &-0.2791\tc{***}  \\*
                                       & {(}2.120{)}     & {(}-3.830{)}    \\ \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LTQ$}        & -0.1854\tc{*}   & -0.4525         \\*
                                       & {(}-0.450{)}    & {(}-0.390{)}    \\ \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\PRF$}        & -0.5240\tc{*}   & -0.0520         \\*
                                       & {(}-3.065{)}    & {(}-1.243{)}    \\ \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\EFF$}        & 0.0262\tc{**}   & -0.0861\tc{***} \\*
                                       & {(}1.733{)}     & {(}-3.350{)}    \\ \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LEV$}        & -0.5640\tc{***} &                 \\*
                                       & {(}-1.430{)}    &                 \\ \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\LG$}         & -0.0270         &                 \\*
                                       & {(}-4.930{)}    &                 \\ \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\AG$}         &                 & 0.0612\tc{***}  \\*
                                       &                 & {(}0.905{)}     \\ \addlinespace
     \multirow{2}[1]{*}{$\DIV$}        &                 & 0.3120\tc{**}   \\*
                                       &                 & {(}2.120{)}     \\ 
     \midrule 
     Year dummy                        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Yes}           \\
     Arellano-Bond test for AR(1)      &   1.156         &  2.452          \\
     Arellano-Bond test for AR(2)      &   0.652         & 1.562           \\
     P-value                           &   00.00         & 00.00           \\
     Sargan test                       & 12.02\tc{***}   & 41.02\tc{***}   \\
   \end{longtable}
   \smallskip

   \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
     \small
      \textit{Note:} This table reports SGMM estimation results of \Cref{eq:1} where non-performing loans to total loans ($\NPL$), and Z-score ($\LnZ$) are the dependent variables for bank $i$ and year $t$. The $\NPL_{i,t-1}$ and $\LnZ_{it-1}$ are lagged dependent variables. $\CEOPC_{it}$ takes a value of one if the bank has explicit political connection,and zero otherwise. $\OwnP$ and $\OwnF$ denotes the Private and Foreign Ownership type . For bank level control variables, The main explanatory variables are defined as follows : Bank size ($\LnTA$), Liquidity ($\LTQ$), Profitability ($\PRF$), Efficiency($\EFF$),  Leverage ($\LEV$), Loan growth ($\LG$), Asset growth ($\AG$) and Diversification ($\DIV$). Detailed definitions for each variable can be found in Section~\ref{sec:Data_variables}. T-statistics are between parentheses.The Sargan test justifies the validity of the over identifying restrictions. Statistical significance indicates \enspace *** $p < 0.01$; \enspace ** $p < 0.05$;\enspace * $p < 0.10$. 
   \end{minipage}
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @leandris Hi, is there please a  suggestion for four data columns

Comment: The approach of switching from a `tabular` to `longtable` is basically the same regadless of how many columns your table has. What did you try so far based on the code I already provided? Apart from that, the code for your second table is not compilable. Please fix that.

Comment: @leandris Hi, I have edited the code, normally it builds an output

Comment: @haithem: Your code still results in a bunch of error messages. Just because you get something that resambles a `.pdf` file, does not mean the code compiles. As long as you get error messages, do not look at the "output"  but fix the error messages first.